# I want to position my captions directly on my images but where screen size changes, captions are left behind. Any fix for this?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, responsive

[image: How captions are displayed on a large viewport]

I have a flex-box with direction set to row containing two divs. The div on the left has a single image while that on the right serves as a container for two sub divs set to column, each containing an image.
I am trying to position the captions midway directly onto the images, but where there is a change in screen size, the captions are left behind floating in the space of the viewport.

I have tried to position the captions absolutely on their corresponding images whiles setting their positions with respect to their containers. However, the dimensions I set rather correspond to the whole viewport and not their containers.
Help!

```
<div id="container">
           <div id="large">
               <img class="img-large" src="large.jpg">
               <div id="caption-span-large">
                   <h3 class="caption">The Dark Playground</h3>
               </div>
           </div>

           <div id="small-frame">
               <div class="small"><img class="img-small" src="small1.png">
                   <div class="caption-span-small1">
                       <h3 class="caption">The Red Night Jedi Camp</h3>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="small"><img class="img-small" src="small2.png">
                   <div class="caption-span-small2">
                       <h3 class="caption">The Red Night Jedi Camp</h3>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

```
#container{
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
}


#large{
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 400px; 
    width: 50%;
    border: lawngreen solid 2px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#small-frame{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    border: lawngreen solid 2px;
}

.small{
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 200px;
    border: green solid 2px;
}

#caption-span-large{
    background-color: rgba(224, 83, 101, 0.63);
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
}

.caption-span-small1{
   background-color: rgba(224, 83, 101, 0.63);
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.caption-span-small2{
    background-color: rgba(224, 83, 101, 0.63);
     border-radius: 10px;
     position: absolute;
}

.caption{
    color: honeydew;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;

    background-color: rgba(224, 83, 101, 0.63);
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 120px;
}

.img-large{
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
    
}

.img-small{
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Use `relative` positioning instead of `absolute`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further on this?

Answer (score 1):

The *position* property set to *absolute* works relative to the closest parent element that has `position: relative`. If there is no such element, then positioning is relative to the top-left corner of the page. Since in your code `position: relative` is specified only for the `#large` block, the layout falls apart.

Therefore, for `.small` blocks, you also need to set `position: relative`.

If I understood the task correctly, then the code will be as follows (*run the snippet, expand the snippet and resize the block by grabbing it by the lower right corner*):

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  /* Only for demo */
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

#large {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  border: lawngreen solid 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#small-frame {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  border: lawngreen solid 2px;
}

.small {
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  border: green solid 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#caption-span-large,
.caption-span-small {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(224, 83, 101, 0.63);
}

.caption {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: honeydew;
  background-color: rgba(224, 83, 101, 0.63);
}

.img-large {
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img-small {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="large">
    <img class="img-large" src="large.jpg">
    <div id="caption-span-large">
      <h3 class="caption">The Dark Playground</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="small-frame">
    <div class="small">
      <img class="img-small" src="small1.png">
      <div class="caption-span-small">
        <h3 class="caption">The Red Night Jedi Camp</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      <img class="img-small" src="small2.png">
      <div class="caption-span-small">
        <h3 class="caption">The Red Night Jedi Camp</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! You're a saviour! I see the "transform" plays a very important role. But what exactly is it doing? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Kay_Erl: Properties `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` center the top-left corner of the element relative to its parent, and `transform: translate (-50%, -50%)` shifts (returns) a block by half of its own width and height.

Comment: Thanks a lot @UModeL! Your explanations really are understandable and helpful 